# Untrack folder locally in git and push to production without deleting

Tags: git

I have a folder `images` which used to be tracked and which i untracked using:
`git rm -r --cached images`.

I also added `images/` to my gitignore. However I am afraid that when I commit and pull on my production server, the images folder will be deleted. The reason is because the github app actually shows the files are deleted.

So how do I prevent locally deleted, then untracked and ignored files to not be deleted on the production server on `git pull`?

Comment: Any reason in particular why you don't want to have this folder under version control?

Comment: Because the people who actually manage the content keep changing the content of the images folder through ftp and not git. Using git for that is overkill

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `git rm --cached`, the files are removed from git, though they're still in your local folder. So after you `push`, the files on sever will be deleted, and so do others' repository when they `pull`.

A better way is to use `git update-index`.

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged images/*
```

It should fulfill your requirement. The only problem is that if others' change these image files and push to git server, you will still get these changes when you `pull`.

Answer (score 1):

I actually did it a different way. Since there are only 2 people using git (me and another developer), we just untracked the folders locally. I then committed the new `.gitignore` and pulled it on the production server. Afterwards i untracked the folder on the production server and voila!

Answer (score 1):

```
git rm  --ignore-unmatch  --cached my_folder/**/**
```

this will untrack ALL FILES in "my_folder" and its subfolders (one level down)

Comment: Exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

One other alternative to consider that might be better for new teammates is using the following in the future for adding directories that are needed, yet omitting their contents:

```
**/images/*
!**/images/readme.md
```

Since Git does not concern itself with empty directories, the trick is to tell Git to not track anything within the `images` directory. But to create the directory in the first place, we need a file, thus in the end we are saying "don't track anything in this directory *except* for this Read Me."